# Find the number of solutions of the inequality $n_{1}+...+n_{k}\leq n$ with each $n_{i}\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: combinatorics

Given that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{P}$.

There should be two approaches to this problem: one is more simple than the other.

Comment: Does $0\in \mathbb N$ for you? (Anyway, add an extra unknown on the left to make the inequality into an equality, and then you essentially have a start-and-bars problem).

Comment: Your last remark gives me the impression that you know the solution. If that is the case, there is not much to do as we know the solution too :)

Comment: Yes, $0\epsilon\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Oh and no, unfortunately I don't know the solution. But I've worked on similar problems which have all had 2 approaches, so I assumed this one would too.

Comment: @Dome, oh then sorry about that. Some people come and ask questions like "I solved this and it is very cool, let's see if you can solve it too.."

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Create a new variable $n_{k+1}$ and count the number of solutions to the equality $n_` + \ldots + n_k + n_{k+1} = n$ with $n_i \in \mathbb{N}, n_{k+1} \geq 0$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just realized that it's an analogue of "stars and bars".... Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

Solve for equality on the RHS from 1 to n. Sum up the total number of solutions.

Approach 2:

**Hint**: Set $ X = n - \sum n_i$.

Comment: +1. Why a downvote?

Comment: @Marvis Oops, by accident... :(

Comment: @Calvin Lin, thanks a lot!!!!!! I would have never thought of your  "Approach 2"!